# How to access all the available themes in vscode?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a directory that holds all available themes in a vscode editor. I know that you can access installed themes via .vscode/extensions/etc, but I'm wondering if there's a master directory of all available themes. For instance, when you use the UI theme picker, it renders a dropdown list of all available themes; is there an easy way for an extension to access this list? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [this](http://orta.io/vscode-themes/) includes all themes but it shows you very many.

Answer (score 0):

Searching `themes` in Extension lists the popular themes

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> lists the 
currently installed themes